# Display a Facebook Page's activity feed on a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, feed

I'm having problems displaying a Facebook feed on a webpage. The purpose is to display the feed of a Facebook Page (http://www.facebook.com/kvaernerasa) on an external page, but I'm missing something.

First of all, I'm using Facebook's own "generator" to create the activity feed box:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

It asks for a domain (http://www.kvaerner.com)...and then what?! I want the feed for a Page, so there is no *app id*. How will it know what feed I'm asking for? I also need the feed to be displayed without requiring that the users are logged in.

I've managed to display the RSS feed (not styled), but would prefer to use Facebook's own plugin. What am I missing here?

Is the Like Box, as mentioned by TommyBs, the only other option? How have other sites implemented this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The Activity Feed plugin shows users what their friends are doing on your site through likes and comments" That's the description from FB. To me that means it doesn't show native facebook page feeds, just information relating to the pages on your site so I don't think it's what you're after

I think what you want is the like-box

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Good point. As far as I can see the Like Box also requires login though. It displays all the posts made by the Page itself, but not what other people do on their Page. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than rolling something yourself I don't think there's another option at present

Comment: If this is true, then I find the Facebook plugins to be lacking, at best. Especially since the RSS feed is readily available.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted since it appears it's the closest thing to what I want. Nonetheless I probably have to resort to manually styling the RSS feed.